# How to pass props to a child React Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Given:

App.jsx > Welcome.js > WorkPlacePage.js

How do I pass props to WorkPlacePage.js so that in WorkPlacePage.js, I can do: `this.props.history.push()`

I'm trying to pass props now but when I console.log, history is being outputted in the console as undefined.

**App.jsx:**

```
import Welcome from '../containers/welcome/Welcome';

const App = ({store}) => {
  return (
    <StoreProvider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/welcome" layout={MainLayout} component={Welcome} />
          <WithMainLayout exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <AuthRoutes path={`/${clientResourceName}`} wrapper={WithMainLayout} />
          <WithMainLayout component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </StoreProvider>
  );
};
```

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import WorkPlacePage from '../../components/welcome/WorkPlacePage';

class Welcome extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 1
    };
  }

  showStep() {
    const {history} = this.props

    console.log('showStep');
    console.log({history})

    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <WorkPlacePage history={history} />
      default:
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Case: Default</h1>
          </div>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    var style = {
      width : (this.state.step / 4 * 100) + '%'
    }
    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step">Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress" style={style}></progress>
        {this.showStep()}
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

**WorkPlacePage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class WorkPlacePage extends React.Component {

  render() {

    console.log('this.props.history')
    console.log(this.props.history)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Workplace</h1>
        <span>
        survey things
        <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/confirmation")}>next page</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WorkPlacePage;
```

**Updated - **

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-apollo": "^1.1.2",
"react-devise": "^0.0.6",
"react-devise-material-ui": "^0.0.1",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"react-redux": "^5.0.4",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
```

Comment: What version of React Router are you using?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6", --- is this what you're looking for? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewLi does this give you what was needed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a push function exported by **react-router-redux**.

You can write an action creator in which you can call push function like this:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

function goTo(pathname) {
    push({ pathname })
}
```

On button click, just dispatch this **goTo** action. It will handle history on its own.

Please remember to add these lines while creating store.

```
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(
  ...
  routerMiddleware(browserHistory),
);

const store = createStore(
  ...
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)
```

Hope it helps.